# Prove that the group generated by sum of two subgroups is isomorphic with their cartesian product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-product

While studying abstract algebra I encountered the following question:

> Given an abelian group $G$ and its two sub-groups $H_1, H_2$, such that $H_1 \cap H_2=\{e\}$, prove that the group generated by $\langle H_1 \cup H_2 \rangle$ is isomorphic with the group $H_1 \times H_2$ (their Cartesian product, with the operation being the one from $G$ along the coordinates, so $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac, bd)$).

From what I understand I should suggest a bijection that preserves the operations of these groups. However I don't quite know how to go about this. I was thinking of the following: for each element $a$ of $\langle H_1 \cup H_2 \rangle$ we first express is at a linear combination of elements from $H_1 \cup H_2$ (so $a = (H_1)_1^{k_1}(H_1)_2^{k_2}...(H_2)_1^{q_1}(H_2)_2^{q_2}...$), separate the elements from $H_1$ and $H_2$ into two expressions ($R_1 = (H_1)_1^{k_1}(H_1)_2^{k_2}..., R_2=(H_2)_1^{q_1}(H_2)_2^{q_2}...$), and place the results of these expressions into their respective coordinates of the pair from the Cartesian product group (so $(R_1, R_2)$). Since $G$ is abelian, we don't have to worry about the order of the operations.

Does such proposition hold any water?

Comment: You need to prove this is a homomorphism and that this homomorphism is invertible

Comment: What you have shown is that the map $H_1\times H_2\to\langle H_1\cup H_2\rangle,\;(a,b)\mapsto ab$ is onto. It is a morphism because $G$ is abelian. Now, compute its kernel ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma**: Let $G$ be a group and $H\le G, K\triangleleft G$ then $H\vee K=HK$

Proof:

1. $HK\subset H\vee K$.
2. $HK\le G$.
3. $H\vee K$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing both $H$ and $K$. $\square$

---

Given $G$ is abelian, hence $H\vee K=HK$.

Verify (or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822450/977780)):

$$\begin{align}
\varphi : H\times K&\to HK,\\
(h, k) &\mapsto hk
\end{align}$$

is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

One way to define the (internal) direct product $G=H\bowtie K$ of two subgroups $H,K$ of a group is that all of the following is satisfied:

- $G=HK$.
- $H\cap K=\{e\}.$
- $H,K\unlhd G$.

It is a standard exercise to show that $H\times K\cong H\bowtie K.$ (For a proof, see **Theorem 9.6** of Gallian's, *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"* or see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2766909/104041).)

---

Let $T=\langle H_1\cup H_2\rangle$.

We have that $H_i=\langle H_i\cup \{e\}\rangle$ is a subgroup of $T$. (As $T$ is the smallest subgroup of the ambient group that contains $H_i$. But $H_i$ is itself a group and so must be a subgroup of $T$.) Since the ambient group is abelian, $T$ is abelian, so each of the subgroups in $T$ is normal; hence $H_i\unlhd T$.

We are given that $H_1\cap H_2=\{ e\}$.

Since, again, $T$ is abelian, we have $T=H_1H_2$ (because any set product $AB$ is a subgroup iff $AB=BA$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197732/104041)).

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
T&\cong H_1 \bowtie H_2\\
&\cong H_1\times H_2.
\end{align}$$

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the OP's question. You could just as well do a one-liner by saying that in the category Ab, the product and coproduct of two groups are the same but what use would that be to the OP?

Comment: It answers the titular question, @Matematleta, and, no, there is nothing stopping you from doing that one-liner.

Comment: @Shaun: you could also replace "We have that Hi=⟨Hi∪{e}⟩ is a subgroup of T. (Use the one-step subgroup test.)" by "Hi is a subgroup of T". And I agree that "this answer doesn't really address the question", because it leaves as "a standard exercise" the proof that $H\times K\cong H\bowtie K$.

Comment: I have added a citation, @AnneBauval. But I disagree: we are not given that $H_i\le T$. It needs to be shown.